# Por qué me da undefined al acabar de recorrer la cadena

Tags: javascript

Al agregar el último número que es el 3, en el click siguiente da undefined ¿Por qué si solo hay 3 elementos recorre un último dando undefined? cómo puedo solucionar eso...

```js
var result = document.getElementById("result");

var add = document.getElementById("add");


var string = ['1','2','3'];

var number = 0;

add.onclick = function() {

result.value = string[number];

number++;

}
```

```html
<input id="result" placeholder="Resultado">
<button id="add">Agregar</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

No hay nada que determine donde termina tu arreglo. Simplemente está buscando la posición `number`.

Y `number` equivale a `0, 1, 2, 3, 4... n`

JavaScript al intentar leer un `arreglo[3]` ya no tiene datos por lo que es indefinido. Debes primeramente verificar el máximo largo de tu arreglo. Para ello puedes usar `arreglo.length`, y verificar que tu `number` no sea mayor al largo - 1. Esto quiere decir un if previo al momento de reemplazar el contenido del input.

```js
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var add = document.getElementById("add");

var string = ['1','2','3'];
var number = 0;

add.onclick = function() {
  if (number < string.length) {
    result.value = string[number];
    number++;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="result" placeholder="Resultado">
<button id="add">Agregar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Por qué si solo hay 3 elementos recorre un último dando undefined?

Porque `undefined` no es un valor o elemento, sino la falta de un valor (en cierto sentido).

¿Qué esperabas que pasara con esto cuando el número llegara a 3, dado que los únicos elementos son en `string[0]`, `string[1]`, y `string[2]`?

```
string[number]
```

No hay un cuarto valor, asi que da nada, osea `undefined`.

Para asegurar que siempre da uno de los tres elementos, hay que escribe esto:

```
string[number % string.length]
```

Esto garantiza que `number` siempre se interprete como un número válido (en este caso, `0`, `1`, o `2`).